# Is it possible to use Scala in CoffeeScript files?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Rails, it's possible to use some server side view logic in CoffeeScript files by simply using the ERB templating language in CoffeeScript files and changing the file extension.

Is there any way to do the same in Play 2.0 - that is, use the Scala used in HTML views in CoffeeScript to perform some server side logic to modify the script files?

The main use case I have in mind for this is to modify the behaviour of some scripts by some configuration file values that are loaded into the scripts through Scala. I'd also welcome best practices for Play 2.0 that accomplish this in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

In Play 1.2 I am doing following to get template language in scripts, assuming you have view.html file, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    #{include '/public/javascripts/script.js'/}
</script>
```

Then you can use same template expressions and variables inside script.js to build dynamic JavaScript based on your server logic.